# Edgers PPA Graphic Drivers Automatic Update

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, games, ppa

This may be a dumb question but does the [Edgers PPA](http://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) provide automatic updating? IE will the Edgers PPA automatically install newer releases of Nvidia drivers? Thanks.

Comment: If by edgers PPA you mean https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa I remember you you shoul'd be using this on a daily work machin and that you could end with a no working X with any new update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if you had activated this PPA in your system all packages will receive updates on performing

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

or from the GUI update manager. This will however not only upgrade your Nvidia graphics drivers but also upgrade all other packages this ppa provides.

Automatic or unattended (security) updates will not be provided by this ppa.

As the Xorg Edgers ppa provides bleeding edge and incompletely tested upgrades you will have a high risk to install instable or buggy packages that in rare cases may even break your system.

> It is therefore **not recommended** to have this ppa active on a productive machine where stability matters.

Also see:

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)
- [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)
- [Notes and warnings for the Xorg Edgers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Comment: :-)  Good one! (and upvoted)